# How can i insert into scraped data into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

//Here is the full script.
I need  to send the returned array results to mysql. I have tried many variations on mySQL insert functions but mysql will still not populate with the data. The table in mysql has the column names 'date','home','score','away'. I am using xamp as a localhost, with database name:'brazil', table name: 'seriea'. Any ideas would be appreciated! thanks.

```
<?php 

$data = array();
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.soccerstats.com/round_details.asp?league=brazil'); //get the html returned from the following url
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

if(!empty($html)){
    $doc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'.$html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $entries = $xpath->query('//table[@class="stat"]');
    foreach($entries as $key => $value) {



        $data[] = array(
            'date' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'home' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(1)->nodeValue),
            'score' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(2)->nodeValue),
            'away' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(3)->nodeValue),
        );
    }
}


echo "<pre>";

print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***");
mysqli_select_db('brazil', $con);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

else
{
$date = $_POST['date'];
$home = $_POST['home'];
$score = $_POST['score'];
$away = $_POST['away'];
$sql="INSERT INTO seriea (date, home, score, away) VALUES ('$date','$home','$score','$away')";
if (!mysqli_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
else{
echo "1 record added";
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

//Output to go to mysql//

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â FluminenseÂ 
            [score] => 1 - 1
            [away] => Â InternacionalÂ 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â VitÃ³riaÂ 
            [score] => 0 - 1
            [away] => Â Sport RecifeÂ 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â CorinthiansÂ 
            [score] => 1 - 1
            [away] => Â BotafogoÂ 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â ChapecoenseÂ 
            [score] => 2 - 1
            [away] => Â BahiaÂ 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â CruzeiroÂ 
            [score] => 3 - 0
            [away] => Â FlamengoÂ 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â SantosÂ 
            [score] => 2 - 0
            [away] => Â CriciÃºmaÂ 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â GrÃªmioÂ 
            [score] => 0 - 0
            [away] => Â PalmeirasÂ 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1 Jun 14
            [home] => Â FigueirenseÂ 
            [score] => 1 - 3
            [away] => Â AtlÃ©tico PRÂ 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [date] => 31 May 14
            [home] => Â SÃ£o PauloÂ 
            [score] => 2 - 1
            [away] => Â AtlÃ©tico MGÂ 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [date] => 31 May 14
            [home] => Â CoritibaÂ 
            [score] => 3 - 0
            [away] => Â GoiÃ¡sÂ 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [date] => 30 May 14
            [home] => Â BahiaÂ 
            [score] => 0 - 2
            [away] => Â SantosÂ 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29 May 14
            [home] => Â InternacionalÂ 
            [score] => 2 - 0
            [away] => Â ChapecoenseÂ 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29 May 14
            [home] => Â FlamengoÂ 
            [score] => 1 - 1
            [away] => Â FigueirenseÂ 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29 May 14
            [home] => Â AtlÃ©tico MGÂ 
            [score] => 2 - 0
            [away] => Â FluminenseÂ 
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29 May 14
            [home] => Â AtlÃ©tico PRÂ 
            [score] => 2 - 2
            [away] => Â SÃ£o PauloÂ 
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29 May 14
            [home] => Â CorinthiansÂ 
            [score] => 1 - 0
            [away] => Â CruzeiroÂ 
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29 May 14
            [home] => Â GoiÃ¡sÂ 
            [score] => 0 - 0
            [away] => Â VitÃ³riaÂ 
        )

)
```

Comment: _it still wont work_ - accurate, succinct and totally useless. Explain what is not working, and what is happening. Oh - and __don't__ mix calls to `mysql_*()` and `mysqli_*()`. Just use `mysqli_*()`.

Comment: hello there, why are you using `$_POST`? the data is inside `$data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `$data` which the data resides, you need to build the query from that. Consider this example:

```
$values = '';
$initial_statement = 'INSERT INTO `seriea` (`date`, `home`, `score`, `away`) VALUES ';
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = "('".implode("','", $value)."')";
}

$values = implode(',', $values);
$complete_statement = $initial_statement . $values;
$query = mysqli_query($con ,$complete_statement);
```

`$complete_statement` should yield something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `seriea` (`date`, `home`, `score`, `away`) VALUES ('1 Jun 14',' Fluminense ','1 - 1',' Internacional '),('1 Jun 14',' Vitória ','0 - 1',' Sport Recife '),('1 Jun 14',' Corinthians ','1 - 1',' Botafogo '),('1 Jun 14',' Chapecoense ','2 - 1',' Bahia '),('1 Jun 14',' Cruzeiro ','3 - 0',' Flamengo '),('1 Jun 14',' Santos ','2 - 0',' Criciúma '),('1 Jun 14',' Grêmio ','0 - 0',' Palmeiras '),('1 Jun 14',' Figueirense ','1 - 3',' Atlético PR '),('31 May 14',' São Paulo ','2 - 1',' Atlético MG '),('31 May 14',' Coritiba ','3 - 0',' Goiás '),('30 May 14',' Bahia ','0 - 2',' Santos '),('29 May 14',' Internacional ','2 - 0',' Chapecoense '),('29 May 14',' Flamengo ','1 - 1',' Figueirense '),('29 May 14',' Atlético MG ','2 - 0',' Fluminense '),('29 May 14',' Atlético PR ','2 - 2',' São Paulo '),('29 May 14',' Corinthians ','1 - 0',' Cruzeiro '),('29 May 14',' Goiás ','0 - 0',' Vitória ')
```

> **`Important Note: Please add this on top of your php file`** 
>   **`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`** 
>   So that you'll get *"Fluminense"* instead of *"Â FluminenseÂ"*